# C# Populating a TreeView with TabControl

Tags: c#, windows, forms, treeview

So I've been able to populate a TreeView with the tabnames in WPF/XAML binding but haven't done this before with C# Windows Forms.

I want to have the treeview display the project name based on what file is open and then tabcontrol names below it (these are static -- one is called editor and the other fields).

I'll add a context menu later, but the sole purpose would be to make the tabs visible based on their state with click events from the treeview.

My problem is I can't figure out how to associate them in the treeview. I found this code, can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track here?

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(Object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {

        // Set the visibility of the tabpages from the treeview 
        if ((e.Action == TreeViewAction.ByMouse))
        {
            if (e.Node.Name == "Editor")
            {
                this.editForm.tabControl1.SelectedTab = editForm.Editor;
            }
            if (e.Node.Name == "Fields")
            {
                this.editForm.tabControl1.SelectedTab = editForm.Fields;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TreeNodes's [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) to hold the associated Tab Name.

```
if (e.Action == TreeViewAction.ByMouse)
{
    TabPage p = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Node.Tag]
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = p;
}
```

Comment: hi there! just saw your response. i actually got it working with the code i edited in my initial question. is that the wrong way to do it?

Comment: it works, however, it requires you to handle each node name individually. What if you add a node name, or change one of the tab names? I think that the most flexible solution, would be that at some point in the initialization of your application you add your TreeItems dynamically based on the TabPages (or vice versa). You can then set the Name of the other and use the method I provided above, except with names. An example of such a method, would be 
`foreach(TabPage tab in tabControl1)
{
  TreeNode node = new TreeNode(tab.Text);
  treeView1.Nodes.add(node);
}`